# only positive numbers in form on symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have one form and I have the field "calories". I need to accept only positive numbers. When I save, I add unit, then I can't set this in the model.

How to do this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Create a [custom validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) and use the following PHP to check if the number is even :

```
if (filter_var($number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
   // its even
}
```

Comment: This answer is not correct based on the question asking for positive numbers, not even numbers